# Verificar quantas datas são iguais

Tags: php

Preciso de uma ajuda para saber quantas datas iguais para que o PHP me apresente em números uma contagem, por exemplo, "3 datas são iguais", oque eu tenho de código até agora é isso:

```
$hoje = '2018-07-02';
$datafinal = '2018-07-02';
if(strtotime($hoje) == strtotime($datafinal){

}
```

Comment: Quantas datas são iguais??? você tem um `array`??? ou somente esse código?

Comment: Estou pegando do banco de dados e comparando com o `date(Y-m-d)` do `php`

Comment: se não faz um group by?

Comment: Você pode pegar essa contagem direto do banco, é mais prático e provavelmente terá maior desempenho. Fazendo uma consulta que te retorne o número de datas iguais

Comment: Vou tentar, qualquer duvida eu volto aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas:

Supondo que esteja fazendo uma seleção no banco:

```
SELECT count(data) as count_data GROUP BY data
```

Ou se você quiser fazer com PHP:

```
$array_datas = [
    '2018-06-10',
    '2018-06-12',
    '2018-06-10',
    '2018-06-10'
];
$hoje = date('Y-m-d');
$iguais = 0;
foreach($array_datas as $data){
    if($data == $hoje){
        $iguais += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso oque está dentro do count seria a coluna da tabela e o ultimo data a comparativa?

Comment: os dois seriam o nome da coluna com a data

Answer (score 0):

Prefira usar o objeto DateTime do PHP.

```
<?php
$hoje   =  
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',date('Y-m-d'));
$datafinal = 
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2018-07-05');
$datasIguais =0;
// $datasIguais = $hoje == $datafinal ? $datasIguais+1 : $datasIguais;
if($hoje == $datafinal){
  $datasIguais++;
}
echo $datasIguais;
```